# vstest.console.exe could not find a custom test logger of x64

Tags: c#, mstest, vstest, vstest.console.exe

I created a custom logger with x64 to log some test result data. When I tried to run the tests, getting **"Error: Could not find a test logger with URI or FriendlyName 'TrxTestLogger'."** . But, working fine when I built with AnyCPU. I have some test dlls which are built in x64 and I am reading them from my custom logger, so I should keep the custom logger to x64. But with x64, not able to find the custom logger.

Steps followed:

1. Created custom logger with the FriendlyName 'TrxTestLogger'.
2. Built with x64.
3. Placed the custom logger dll into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Extensions

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you run `vstest.console.exe /ListLoggers`? What do you have in output? Did you run it with `/Platform` switch?

Comment: I ran vstest.console.exe /ListLoggers, the same thing is happening. When I built custom logger with AnyCPU the logger is showing in the available list. But when I built with x64, it is not showing. And same with /platform:x64. I don't have any idea why the logger built in x64 is not recognizing?